# express locallibrary tutorial author names missing from book list

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I'm trying to build some knowledge in back end development (because I need it!) after spending a few years on front end, and after a short intro' into [**Basic Node and Express**](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/back-end-development-and-apis/basic-node-and-express/meet-the-node-console) from the fantastic [**FreeCodeCamp Curriculum**](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn)  I'm now trying to follow the [**MDN Express Locallibrary Tutorial**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Tutorial_local_library_website) . Everything was going well until the **Book List** page.

When I click on the **All Books** link the app should render a list of all the books along with the names of the author of each book. I'm getting the list of books OK, but the author names are missing.

I'm not getting any error messages per se, however, when I hover over the `allBooks` variable in the `async handler` (I'm using VS Code) I notice that the `author` value seems somewhat amiss as there is a question mark after the `author` key and the value has `Types.ObjectID` followed by `null | undefined`

```
const allBooks: Omit<Document<unknown, {}, {
    title: string;
    summary: string;
    isbn: string;
    genre: Types.ObjectId[];
    author?: Types.ObjectId | null | undefined;
}> & {
    title: string;
    summary: string;
    isbn: string;
    genre: Types.ObjectId[];
    author?: Types.ObjectId | null | undefined;
} & {
    ...;
}, never>[]
```

Now, I typed most of the code up by hand initially, just to get used the format and syntax of using [Mongoose ODM](https://mongoosejs.com/) along with [PugJS](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) template engine and after a day or so of failing to find the source of the problem I've been through the tutorial from the start and copied & pasted the code into each of the individual files in the app and I still have the exact same problem.

There are many questions posted on this forum regarding the tutorial, but none specific to this case. I did find that this problem had occurred before though: [Author's Name Not Rendering](https://github.com/mdn/express-locallibrary-tutorial/issues/80) but that appears to have been fixed back in 2020. I noticed during the git Hub discussion that there were concerns over the state of the DB at the time. With that in mind, I dropped all tables from the Mongo DB and re-populated it with the original data, because I thought there may have been a chance that I had corrupted the data at some point. That hasn't fixed the problem and I'm not sure where to go from here. I feel that if I just ignore the problem, it's not going to go away, and could well come back and bite me later down the trail.

What I did find was that if I use `#{book.author}` instead of `#{book.author.name}` in the `book_list.pug` file then the app renders the authors' `_Id` from the database. This tells me it has to be something to do with the virtual type `name` which is defined on the `AuthorSchema` but, that's as far as my skills will take me. I'm just not familiar enough with this stack tech to know how to fix this.

My code for the app is below.

**Models**

**author.js**

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const AuthorSchema = new Schema({
  first_name: { type: String, required: true, maxLength: 100 },
  family_name: { type: String, required: true, maxLength: 100 },
  date_of_birth: { type: Date },
  date_of_death: { type: Date },
});

AuthorSchema.virtual("name").get(function () {
  // To avoid erros where an author doesn't have a family name or first name
  // we want to make sure we handle the exception by returning an empty string for that case

  let fullname = "";
  if (this.first_name && this.last_name) {
    fullname = `${this.family_name}, ${this.first_name}`;
  }

  return fullname;
});

// Virtual for author's URL returns an absolute URL
// we'll use this property in our templates whenever we want to get a link for an author
AuthorSchema.virtual("url").get(function () {
  // We don't want to use arrow functions because we'll need to us this object
  return `/catalog/author/${this._id}`;
});

// Export the `Author` model
module.exports = mongoose.model("Author", AuthorSchema);
```

**book.js**

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const BookSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Author", required: true },
  summary: { type: String, required: true },
  isbn: { type: String, required: true },
  genre: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Genre" }],
});

//  Virtual for book's URL
BookSchema.virtual("url").get(function () {
  // We don't want to use arrow functions as we'll need the `this` object
  return `/catalog/book/${this._id}`;
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Book", BookSchema);
```

**Controllers**

**bookController.js**

```js
// book controller
// The controllers use the `express-async-handler module` which will
// catch any exceptions thrown in our route handler functions,
// this needs to be installed using `npm install express-async-handler`

const Book = require("../models/book");
const Author = require("../models/author");
const Genre = require("../models/genre");
const BookInstance = require("../models/bookinstance");

const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
const author = require("../models/author");

exports.index = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  // Get details of books, book instances, authors and genre counts (in parallel)
  const [
    numBooks,
    numBookInstances,
    numAvailableBookInstances,
    numAuthors,
    numGenres,
  ] = await Promise.all([
    Book.countDocuments({}).exec(),
    BookInstance.countDocuments({}).exec(),
    BookInstance.countDocuments({ status: "Available" }).exec(),
    Author.countDocuments({}).exec(),
    Genre.countDocuments({}).exec(),
  ]);

  res.render("index", {
    title: "Local Library Home",
    book_count: numBooks,
    book_instance_count: numBookInstances,
    book_instance_available_count: numAvailableBookInstances,
    author_count: numAuthors,
    genre_count: numGenres,
  });
});

// Display list of all books.
exports.book_list = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const allBooks = await Book.find({}, "title author")
    .sort({ title: 1 })
    .populate("author")
    .exec();

  res.render("book_list", { title: "Book List", book_list: allBooks });
});

// Display detail page for a specific book.
exports.book_detail = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  res.send(`NOT IMPLEMENTED: Book detail: ${req.params.id}`);
});

// Display book create form on GET.
exports.book_create_get = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  res.send("NOT IMPLEMENTED: Book create GET");
});

// Handle book create on POST.
exports.book_create_post = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  res.send("NOT IMPLEMENTED: Book create POST");
});

// Display book delete form on GET.
exports.book_delete_get = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  res.send("NOT IMPLEMENTED: Book delete GET");
});

// Handle book delete on POST.
exports.book_delete_post = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  res.send("NOT IMPLEMENTED: Book delete POST");
});

// Display book update form on GET.
exports.book_update_get = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  res.send("NOT IMPLEMENTED: Book update GET");
});

// Handle book update on POST.
exports.book_update_post = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  res.send("NOT IMPLEMENTED: Book update POST");
});
```

**authorController**

```js
const Author = require("../models/author");
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");

// Display list of all Authors.
exports.author_list = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  res.send("NOT IMPLEMENTED: Author list");
});

// Display detail page for a specific Author.
exports.author_detail = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  res.send(`NOT IMPLEMENTED: Author detail: ${req.params.id}`);
});

// Display Author create form on GET.
exports.author_create_get = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  res.send("NOT IMPLEMENTED: Author create GET");
});

// Handle Author create on POST.
exports.author_create_post = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  res.send("NOT IMPLEMENTED: Author create POST");
});

// Display Author delete form on GET.
exports.author_delete_get = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  res.send("NOT IMPLEMENTED: Author delete GET");
});

// Handle Author delete on POST.
exports.author_delete_post = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  res.send("NOT IMPLEMENTED: Author delete POST");
});

// Display Author update form on GET.
exports.author_update_get = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  res.send("NOT IMPLEMENTED: Author update GET");
});

// Handle Author update on POST.
exports.author_update_post = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  res.send("NOT IMPLEMENTED: Author update POST");
});
```

**Routes**

**catalog.js**

```js
// Import the Express application & create a router
const express = require("express");
// The routes are all set up on the router which is then exported
const router = express.Router();

// Require controller modules.
const book_controller = require("../controllers/bookController");
const author_controller = require("../controllers/authorController");
const genre_controller = require("../controllers/genreController");
const book_instance_controller = require("../controllers/bookinstanceController");

/// BOOK ROUTES ///

// GET catalog home page.
router.get("/", book_controller.index);

// GET request for creating a Book. NOTE This must come before routes that display Book (uses id).
router.get("/book/create", book_controller.book_create_get);

// POST request for creating Book.
router.post("/book/create", book_controller.book_create_post);

// GET request to delete Book.
router.get("/book/:id/delete", book_controller.book_delete_get);

// POST request to delete Book.
router.post("/book/:id/delete", book_controller.book_delete_post);

// GET request to update Book.
router.get("/book/:id/update", book_controller.book_update_get);

// POST request to update Book.
router.post("/book/:id/update", book_controller.book_update_post);

// GET request for one Book.
router.get("/book/:id", book_controller.book_detail);

// GET request for list of all Book items.
router.get("/books", book_controller.book_list);

/// AUTHOR ROUTES ///

// GET request for creating Author. NOTE This must come before route for id (i.e. display author).
router.get("/author/create", author_controller.author_create_get);

// POST request for creating Author.
router.post("/author/create", author_controller.author_create_post);

// GET request to delete Author.
router.get("/author/:id/delete", author_controller.author_delete_get);

// POST request to delete Author.
router.post("/author/:id/delete", author_controller.author_delete_post);

// GET request to update Author.
router.get("/author/:id/update", author_controller.author_update_get);

// POST request to update Author.
router.post("/author/:id/update", author_controller.author_update_post);

// GET request for one Author.
router.get("/author/:id", author_controller.author_detail);

// GET request for list of all Authors.
router.get("/authors", author_controller.author_list);

/// GENRE ROUTES ///

// GET request for creating a Genre. NOTE This must come before route that displays Genre (uses id).
router.get("/genre/create", genre_controller.genre_create_get);

//POST request for creating Genre.
router.post("/genre/create", genre_controller.genre_create_post);

// GET request to delete Genre.
router.get("/genre/:id/delete", genre_controller.genre_delete_get);

// POST request to delete Genre.
router.post("/genre/:id/delete", genre_controller.genre_delete_post);

// GET request to update Genre.
router.get("/genre/:id/update", genre_controller.genre_update_get);

// POST request to update Genre.
router.post("/genre/:id/update", genre_controller.genre_update_post);

// GET request for one Genre.
router.get("/genre/:id", genre_controller.genre_detail);

// GET request for list of all Genre.
router.get("/genres", genre_controller.genre_list);

/// BOOKINSTANCE ROUTES ///

// GET request for creating a BookInstance. NOTE This must come before route that displays BookInstance (uses id).
router.get(
  "/bookinstance/create",
  book_instance_controller.bookinstance_create_get
);

// POST request for creating BookInstance.
router.post(
  "/bookinstance/create",
  book_instance_controller.bookinstance_create_post
);

// GET request to delete BookInstance.
router.get(
  "/bookinstance/:id/delete",
  book_instance_controller.bookinstance_delete_get
);

// POST request to delete BookInstance.
router.post(
  "/bookinstance/:id/delete",
  book_instance_controller.bookinstance_delete_post
);

// GET request to update BookInstance.
router.get(
  "/bookinstance/:id/update",
  book_instance_controller.bookinstance_update_get
);

// POST request to update BookInstance.
router.post(
  "/bookinstance/:id/update",
  book_instance_controller.bookinstance_update_post
);

// GET request for one BookInstance.
router.get("/bookinstance/:id", book_instance_controller.bookinstance_detail);

// GET request for list of all BookInstance.
router.get("/bookinstances", book_instance_controller.bookinstance_list);

// Export the router
module.exports = router;
```

**index.js**

```js
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
// router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
//   res.render("index", { title: "Express Yourself!" });
// });

// GET home page.
router.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.redirect("/catalog");
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Views**

**book_list.pug**

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  if book_list.length
    ul
      each book in book_list
        li
          a(href=book.url) #{book.title}
          |  (#{book.author.name})

  else
    p There are no books.
```

**index.pug**

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #[em LocalLibrary], a very basic Express website developed as a tutorial example on the Mozilla Developer Network.

  h1 Dynamic content

  p The library has the following record counts:

  ul
    li #[strong Books:] !{book_count}
    li #[strong Copies:] !{book_instance_count}
    li #[strong Copies available:] !{book_instance_available_count}
    li #[strong Authors:] !{author_count}
    li #[strong Genres:] !{genre_count}
```

**layout.pug**

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  head
    title= title
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N", crossorigin="anonymous")
    script(src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js", integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj", crossorigin="anonymous")
    script(src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js", integrity="sha384-+sLIOodYLS7CIrQpBjl+C7nPvqq+FbNUBDunl/OZv93DB7Ln/533i8e/mZXLi/P+", crossorigin="anonymous")
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    div(class='container-fluid')
      div(class='row')
        div(class='col-sm-2')
          block sidebar
            ul(class='sidebar-nav')
              li
                a(href='/catalog') Home
              li
                a(href='/catalog/books') All books
              li
                a(href='/catalog/authors') All authors
              li
                a(href='/catalog/genres') All genres
              li
                a(href='/catalog/bookinstances') All book-instances
              li
                hr
              li
                a(href='/catalog/author/create') Create new author
              li
                a(href='/catalog/genre/create') Create new genre
              li
                a(href='/catalog/book/create') Create new book
              li
                a(href='/catalog/bookinstance/create') Create new book instance (copy)

        div(class='col-sm-10')
          block content
```

**Application**

**app.js**

```js
const createError = require("http-errors");
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const logger = require("morgan");

// Import the routes
var indexRouter = require("./routes/index");
var usersRouter = require("./routes/users");
const catalogRouter = require("./routes/catalog"); //Import routes for "catalog" area of site

const app = express();

// DB connection
// Set up mongoose connection
// NB: just for dev purposes. Do this more safely for production
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
const mongoDB =
  "mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.llbncdg.mongodb.net/local_library?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

main().catch((err) => console.log(err));
async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect(mongoDB);
}

// view engine setup
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "pug");

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

// make Express serve all the files in the .public directory
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.use("/", indexRouter);
app.use("/users", usersRouter);
app.use("/catalog", catalogRouter); // Add catalog routes to middleware chain.

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get("env") === "development" ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render("error");
});

module.exports = app;
```

**www**

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('express-locallibrary-tutorial:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

I left out files that I think are irrelevant, but let me know if I missed something   and I'll post it.

Thanks to anyone who casts there eyes over this, I appreciate the time it takes.

Comment: You should really focus on the **minimal** in [mre]. Why aren't you using `ref: 'Author'` like you have with `ref: 'Genre'`? See the Mongoose guide for populating relations ~ https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: potential fix ```
AuthorSchema.virtual("name").get(function () {\n
  let fullname = "";\n
  if (this.first_name && this.family_name) {\n
    fullname = `${this.family_name}, ${this.first_name}`;\n
  }\n
  return fullname;\n
});
```

Comment: @phil Apologies, with hindsight, I could have omitted some of the code, I just wanted to present the complete files, just in-case there was something lurking in the depths that I hadn't spotted. I thought I had included the reference to the `Author` model but must have un-done that original omission at some point. I fixed that now and will update my post with `author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Author", required: true },` as it should be.

Comment: @Phil family_name instead of last_name

Comment: @weshouman that was well spotted, sometimes you can't see the wood for the trees. That fixed the problem, if you post it as an answer I mark it as the solution. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is almost correct, there's just a typo in the author model where the `last_name` was used instead of the `family_name`

For example

```
  if (this.first_name && this.last_name) {
    ...
  }
```

Should be

```
  if (this.first_name && this.family_name) {
     ...
  }
```

Comment: yep! That was the culprit. I don't know how many times I looked at that model but my brain just saw `last_name` == `family_name` it never ceases to amaze me how the brain works (or not) sometimes! Thanks for your input on this.